# SQL Server Service Broker DSQL operation on another database causing Broker failure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service-broker

I have established a Service Broker configuration based on Eitan Blumin's excellent example.

https://eitanblumin.com/2018/10/31/advanced-service-broker-sample-asynchronous-triggers/

I have crafted my own stored procedure. I can get the example to work when I'm performing activities within the same database. If I try to operate outside the current database, I get errors.

I'm new to Service Brokers and I'm having trouble capturing the error but I suspect this is all part of the same problem.

This works

```
DELETE FROM CurrentDB.dbo.[gis_pt_im_map_auth_label] 
WHERE plotnumber IN (' + @ids + ')
```

This fails

```
DELETE FROM OtherDB.OtherSchema.[gis_pt_im_map_auth_label] 
WHERE plotnumber IN (' + @ids + ')
```

Below is the stored procedure in question. I suspect it is some kind of user permission but I have tried a couple of user based changes like making the executing user the DBO of both databases and no result.

For clarity if I execute the stored procedure manually, this will run. However Service Brokers changes the nature of the execution.

Any thoughts or inputs appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Location_UPDATE_TEST3] 
    @inserted XML,
    @deleted  XML = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(max)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM @inserted.nodes('inserted/row') AS T(X))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[LocationViewLog] ([lo_location], [lo_Location_Code])
            SELECT 
                inserted.[lo_location],
                inserted.lo_location_Code            
            FROM
                (SELECT
                     --X.query('.').value('(row/PurchaseOrderID)[1]', 'int') AS PurchaseOrderID
                     X.query('.').value('(row/lo_Location)[1]', 'int') AS lo_location,
                     X.query('.').value('(row/lo_Location_Code)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS lo_location_Code
                 FROM 
                     @inserted.nodes('inserted/row') AS T(X)) AS inserted 

           SELECT @ids = String_agg(inserted.lo_location, ',')
                    FROM 
                    (SELECT
                         X.query('.').value('(row/lo_Location)[1]', 'int') AS lo_location
                    FROM @inserted.nodes('inserted/row') AS T(X)
                     ) AS inserted 

--The following block is what is problematic.
--if I try to execute this delete in another database the Service Broker breaks as a result of an error.
--If I craft this same command to operate in the current database there's no problem
            SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM Test.dbo.[gis_pt_im_map_auth_label] WHERE  plotnumber IN ('+@ids+')';
                       INSERT INTO [dbo].[LocationViewLog]
                   (lo_Location_Code) VALUES (@SQL);
            EXEC(@SQL) 
--END Problem Block
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Since we're in an Asynchronous Trigger, rolling back an update operation
        -- is a lot more complicated than in a regular trigger.
        -- For now, for this scenario we'll take the risk of having partial data.

        EXECUTE [dbo].[uspLogError];
    END CATCH;
```

**EDIT. The answer provided by David Browne was indeed the issue. I found the follwo=ing two links to be exactly what I needed and demonstrated the implementation of Module Signing I needed.
https://sqlundercover.com/2018/05/02/digitally-signing-a-stored-procedure-to-allow-it-to-run-with-elevated-permissions/

https://sqlundercover.com/2018/10/30/signing-stored-procedures-that-access-multiple-databases/

Comment: log stuff like SUSER_NAME() and USER_NAME() in your error logger so you know which user is actually in the context and see if he actually has the rights, what does the error say?

Comment: [CAUTION:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#procedure_name) _Avoid the use of the `sp_` prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name._

Comment: Not SB-related, but instead of building dynamic SQL with a comma-separated list of IDs, could you instead put those IDs into a temp table and use that to drive your delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Service Broker Internal Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/internal-activation-context?view=sql-server-ver16#security-context) runs your activation procedure using SQL Server impersonation.  And SQL Server impersonation is limited to the current database.

> A short explanation of the problem is that the activation execution
> context is trusted only in the database, not in the whole server.
> Anything related to the whole server, like a server level view or a
> dynamic management view or a linked server, acts as if you logged in
> as [Public].
>
> The recommended way to solve the issue is to sign the procedure with a
> server level certificate that has the proper rights needed for the
> operation in question

[Why does feature … not work under activation?](http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/)

To sign the stored procedure, follow the instructions here:
[Tutorial: Signing Stored Procedures with a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16)